# Field Create Dynamically

Tags: apex, soap-api, webservices, soap

I am working with SOAP integration Is it possible creation of field in salesforce
Dynamically, Based upon SOAP Request

Example-->>

```
Product      Qunatity       Price

pen           2            10

pen           3            9
```

CanAny one give me some sample, if it possible means.

May i know how can i update my code as per metadata Api

```
List<Quote_Item__c> qilist = new List<Quote_Item__c>();
   for(QuoteLineWrapper wrapper : req.qlines){      
  Quote_Item__c qi = new Quote_Item__c();
     qi.Name = wrapper.qlineName;
   qi.Quantity__c = wrapper.quantity;
    qi.Unit_Price__c = wrapper.unitprice;
    qi.Orginal_Price__c = wrapper.orgPrice;
    qilist.add(qi); 
   }

  //MAP QUOTEITEM TO QUOTE AND PRODUCT
   for(Integer rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < qlist.size(); rowIdx++)
    qilist[rowIdx].Quote__c =qlist[rowIdx].Id       

   for(Integer rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < lstProduct.size(); rowIdx++)
    qilist[rowIdx].Product__c =lstProduct[rowIdx].Id;

      insert qilist;
```

Comment: You can create fields dynamically using the Salesforce Metadata API, but i sense that might not be what your asking here? Can you give a bit more information and background, the example you give does not seem to relate to your question? What is your actual requirement?

Comment: @Andrew Actually from third party application i am getting same product but 2 diffenrt qunaties, 2 differnt prices but these all are belongs under same Quote.But in sfdc i have only 1 qunatity, 1 price fields, if 2 qunatity, 2 price will come how can i map that values in my custom webservice.

Comment: Ok, but what does this have to do with 'Is it possible creation of field in salesforce Dynamically'? Sorry still a little lost with your question...

Comment: @Andrew I want to create a field dynamically in salesforce based upon the soap request.May i know is it possible or not...??

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm a bit confused more than ever now, are you really sure you want to 'create a new custom field' here? I cannot see in your code any place where you are needing to do this?

Comment: @Andrew My custom webservice is work for when i get 1 quantity, 1 unit price value for Product1, If i get Quantity2 and unitprice2 for thae product1 at that situation i have to create a new field for quantity2 and unitprice2 ..May i know how i do this.

Comment: Ok now I see thanks, I'll try and update my answer, though I don't think this is really the direction you need to take dynamically anyway.

Comment: @Andrew Can you Suggest Me how can i modify my custom webservice.for field creation dynamically.

Comment: See my answer and the code sample, links I've given, you can paste this code in and try it, though you will soon find as i have hinted in my answer, the async nature of the Metadata API will cause you further problems, leading to further complexity in creating a separate process to outside of your web service to update the fields created, for this you will need to queue up the requests in a separate object etc. Quite a lot more complexity and still not 100% accurate, as what do you do if multiple requests arrive concurrently? See my Summary for my final thoughts on this for you. :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Salesforce Metadata API.** It is possible to create a field dynamically in Salefsorce using the [Salesforce Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/), which is a SOAP Web Service API which can be called from a number of langauges and platforms. You can see an example and further reading on how to do this in Apex from this [repository](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) and this blog [here](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/10/27/introduction-to-calling-the-metadata-api-from-apex/). The following is an example...

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
customField.fullName = 'Test__c.TestField__c';
customField.label = 'Test Field';
customField.type_x = 'Text';
customField.length = 42;
MetadataService.AsyncResult[] results =
    service.create(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { customField });
```

**Applying this to your use case**. In your case you want to dynamically create two new fields if additional information is provided in your soap request. The main problem I see with this and the Metadata API (which is the only way to programatically create fields). Is this API is asynchronous meaning (as per the linked blog) you need to poll (since you cannot pause execution either) for the results until you get to know if the field has been created or not. Thus you will not be able to create the field and populate it in the same SOAP request as I think your hoping to do.

**Summary.** I would have thought it might be better to simply create enough fields up front and conditionally populate them based on the data you receive. Since even if you managed to work around the above (with some kind of differed updating of your rows after field create). Surely you need to also update layouts to show the new fields? So in my view I think you should probably head towards creating a set of these fields up front via the standard way in Salesforce and then populate them as and when needed.

Comment: getting good mileage from that repo!

Comment: @Andrew Can you suggest me where can i include your  code in my custom webservice my code is

Comment: List<Quote_Item__c> qilist = new List<Quote_Item__c>();
       for(QuoteLineWrapper wrapper : req.qlines){      
        Quote_Item__c qi = new Quote_Item__c();
         qi.Name = wrapper.qlineName;
       qi.Quantity__c = wrapper.quantity;
        qi.Unit_Price__c = wrapper.unitprice;
        qi.Orginal_Price__c = wrapper.orgPrice;
        qilist.add(qi); 
       }

Comment: //MAP QUOTEITEM TO QUOTE AND PRODUCT
   for(Integer rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < qlist.size(); rowIdx++)
        qilist[rowIdx].Quote__c =qlist[rowIdx].Id; for(Integer rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < lstProduct.size();rowIdx++)
        qilist[rowIdx].Product__c =lstProduct[rowIdx].Id;
          insert qilist

Comment: Can you update your answer with this code so its easier to read please.

Comment: What is the business value of creating extra fields just because the price and quantity is different? why not just add a separate line item Opportunity line item and/or quote line item? or calculate the correct price and quantity based on the number of items you get?

Comment: Thats a very good question actually, i tend to stay away from the reasoning behind the question, as we try to answer the questions directly, but in this case i think the author of this question probably does need to take a step (or two back), your question should also go on his question as well tbh...

Comment: @Sven your answer is ok, but while i am sending quote to customer he have to knows that for quantity 2 ---$10, quantity 3-->>$9, as per your answer if i mix both means customer get confused,how much he getting discount for quantity2,quantity3..for products.

Comment: @sven that's why i have to create a new field..if it possible means could you update my code.

Comment: @Sathya can you clarify why the code and comments clarifying above do not give the means to update your own code?

Comment: @Andrew it is not possible to insert metadata api code in my custom soap webservice

Comment: Yep, just paste it in and execute accordingly when you have the additional field values. But keep in mind the added complexity since the API is of the async kind (you could wait for Spring'14 to use the none async versions). As I've said above once you paste the code to create the fields, you'll have to start a batch job to check the fields have been created then populate the fields.

Comment: In all honesty, going down this path is going to give you more and more questions and complications, just create the fields up front is what i advise strongly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need many quotes for a single item.  Rather than add columns dynamically, you should look at creating related records dynamically.

For example, if you have a Quotable_Item__c object, it might have a couple properties like name, dimensions, etc.  Then you can create an Item_Quote object as such

Quotable_Item__c : the stuff that varies depending on who is selling the service/item.

- Name
- Description__c
- Type__c (service or product?)
- Dimensions__c (optional)
- Weight__c (optional)
- Material__c (optional)
- (do NOT add price or quantity here -- those belong in the next object)

Item_Quote__c: contains properties that vary depending on context (who is offering the item at a certain price quote, for example).

- Quoted_Item__c - Lookup field points to Quotable_Item__c.
- Price__c - currency
- Quantity__c - number
- Frequency_Description__c - (text) - for subscription/service type quotes. e.g. 'charged biweekly'.
- Source__c - (string/text) - Name/description of source of the quote.

Then when you are building out a page, show a related list of Quotes.  When writing apex code, you can query for all related items with a secondary SELECT statement.

```
Quotable_Item__c item = [select ... from Quotable_Item__c WHERE ...];
List<Item_Quote> quotes = [SELECT Price__c, Quantity__c, Source__c, Id FROM Price_Quote__c WHERE Quoted_Item__c = :item.Id];
```

If you have additional random fields whose meaning really can vary widely, you may want to create another field called 'Additional_Data__c' that contains JSON or key-value pairs as text, or another related object with a Key__c and Value__c properties.  But I strongly recommend against either of these.  In most cases you should only accept data you are prepared to handle in an organized way.

Don't create multiple fields that mean the same thing (Price1, Price2, Price3...) -- this indicates a need for a separate related object.